# facebook graph via cUrl

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

Is it possible to post something to fb group via **cUrl**?
I need to use cUrl because script will run through console.
Maybe someone can provide en example?

I was trying to use something like this:

```
  ...
 public function postUrl($url, $params)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params, null, '&'));
    $ret = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $ret;
}

public function getAccessToken($app_id, $secret)
{
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
    $token_params = array(
        "type" => "client_cred",
        "client_id" => $app_id,
        "client_secret" => $secret
    );
    return str_replace('access_token=', '', $this->postUrl($url, $token_params));
}
```

and then:

```
    $token = $this->getAccessToken('appID', 'appSecret');

    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed";
    $postData = "&message=" . urlencode('test message....')
        . "&access_token=" . $token;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($output);
    curl_close($ch);
```

and got the error: ***An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500***

Comment: So, have you checked the resulting access token with the Debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

Comment: Just tested it and debug says that it belongs to:
App ID 607180716056430 : BloodCenter, its my app

Comment: OK, so it's not expired, and you have gathered the `publish_actions` permission? See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed/#publish

Comment: Just readed documentation one more time and realize that i need first of all get the code from https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/ and then use this code to get access_token. Just try to use such token in my code and i can post from curl. But how can i get the code from https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/ via curl?

Comment: I thought you have an access token?

Comment: no, after reading documentation, i figured out that i need to get code from dialog/authorize and with this code i need request for the access_token, and then it will works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60884/discussion-between--and-tobi).